# How does Nutiteq EditableLayer adds a polygon automatically?

Tags: java, android, nutiteq

I'm looking at the codes to find the parameters of [this](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=7f1405ed43&view=fimg&th=1499a08fecb5f744&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1484394041827131392-local0&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ-B_t4stL-_sskod-Nytkq3x2p_nWdiQ2QXBOpii4vPJ6N4K4u4S62M_pzGBZFL7aG8MM3YxYyseKF7bWVmEpfOCLOC5h-l86ZQfOWF8vbXUOBmHfi7tlf5CBc&ats=1415628526740&rm=1499a08fecb5f744&zw&sz=w1342-h540) triangle shaped polygons parameters. But I just can't find it.

```
final String[] items = new String[] { "Point", "Line", "Polygon", "Poligon (Koordinat)" };
    typeBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            switch (item) {
            case 0:
                mapView.createElement(Point.class, userData);
                break;
            case 1:
                mapView.createElement(Line.class, userData);
                break;
            case 2:
                mapView.createElement(Polygon.class, userData);
                break;
```

I'm just trying to add my own polygon with coordinates and I want this polygon to be an editable one.
Can someone explain me how does this automatic editable polygon is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polygons are defined in https://github.com/nutiteq/advancedlayers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nutiteq/editable/EditableMapView.java , method  `public VectorElement createElement()` . If you extend the `EditableMapView`, then you should get what you want.